# How to create a List<SystemSound> with music from recourses

Tags: c#

Hello How to create a `List<SystemSound>` with music from recourses?

I try this, but i get below exception:

```
    List<System.Media.SystemSound> music = new List<System.Media.SystemSound>
    {
        global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.music_quit_1,
        global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.music_quit_2,
        global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.music_quit_3,
        global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.music_quit_4,
    };
```

> "Argument 1: Can not convert from System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream to
>   System.Media.SystemSound."

From that I will random on music and after play it.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there a compiler error? An exception? Be precise!

Comment: Sorry. If i want try to run it write "Argument 1: Can not convert from System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream to System.Media.SystemSound."

Comment: music_quit_1 is a system sound or some other sound?

Comment: What is the format of music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `System.Media.SystemSound` is not used this way, this class is only used to represent a **system sound type** such as `Asterisk`, `Beep`, `Hand`, `Question` or `Exclamation`. A **system sound** can be played through `SystemSounds`.

**Example**

```
SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

This example will play the **system sound** `Asterisk`. This is similar to `System.Drawing.Brush` as you can not say `System.Drawing.Brush.Black` but you can say `System.Drawing.Brushes.Black`. `System.Drawing.Brush` was only used to define an object of name `Black` in a new class of name `System.Drawing.Brushes` as a color `Black`. We can see this in the definition of `System.Drawing.Brushes`

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets a system-defined System.Drawing.Brush object.
//
// Returns:
//     A System.Drawing.Brush object set to a system-defined color.
public static Brush Black { get; }
```

Moreover, if you would like to play a new **Wave Sound**, you may create a new class of `SoundPlayer` which controls playback of a sound from a **Sound Wave**(.wav) file

**Example**

```
SoundPlayer _SoundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(); //Initializes a new SoundPlayer of name _SoundPlayer
_SoundPlayer.SoundLocation = @"D:\Resources\International\Greetings.wav"; //Sets the target Wave Sound file to D:\...\Greetings.wav
_SoundPlayer.Play(); //Plays the target Wave Sound file
```

If you still would like to use a Generic `List`. Then, perhaps the following example may help you

**Example**

```
List<string> WaveSoundCollections = new List<string> { @"D:\Resources\International\Greetings.wav", @"D:\Resources\International\Good-Bye.wav" }; //Initializes a new Generic Collection of class List of type string and injecting TWO strings into the Generic Collection
SoundPlayer NewPlayer = new SoundPlayer(); //Initializes a new SoundPlayer
if (Client.Start) //Client refers to a particular Class that has Start and End as bool
{
    NewPlayer.SoundLocation = WaveSoundCollections[0]; //Set the SoundLocation of NewPlayer to D:\Resources\International\Greetings.wav
    NewPlayer.Play(); //Plays the target Wave Sound file
}
else if (Client.End)
{
    NewPlayer.SoundLocation = WaveSoundCollections[1]; //Set the SoundLocation of NewPlayer to D:\Resources\International\Good-Bye.wav
    NewPlayer.Play(); //Plays the target Wave Sound file
}
```

**Notice**: `SoundPlayer` is **only** used to play **Wave Sound** files. If you would like to play other media files such as **.mp3**, **.mpeg**, etc... Then, you may use `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer` which can be imported from the `Object Browser` to create a new class of `MediaPlayer` and play a particular file.

**Example**

```
string TargetFile = @"D:\File.mp3";
MediaPlayer _MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
_MediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(TargetFile));
_MediaPlayer.Play();
```

**IMPORTANT**: To use `MediaPlayer`, you have to add a new reference of `WindowsBase`.

To add a new reference of `WindowsBase`, try the following:

- Right-click **References** from the **Solution Explorer** and select **Add Reference...**
- Select **WindowsBase** and click on **OK**
- Make sure that the new reference you've just added has its property of bool of name **Copy Local** set to **True** so that the client won't encounter errors during initialization

  [image: It's important to set CopyLocal to True in such cases]

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: I have included WindowBase in my C# project but it does not have media player object. @Picrofo EGY

Comment: @MuhammadUmar `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer` is not imported to a particular project by default. [You'll have to import it through `Object Browser` to use it.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kJpMm.png). However, if you try to use it without adding a reference to `WindowsBase`, you'll get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ut80l.png) error. That's why `WindowsBase` is required. It's also important to set `Copy Local` to `True` through the properties of the reference so that the client won't encounter errors during initialization. Have a nice day :)